# how to keep data id clicked after ajax post setTimeout reload

Tags: jquery, ajax

how to keep id tag clicked after ajax post setTimeout reload ?

HTML

```html
<a id="star" class="toto">sort by star</a>
<a id="date" class="toto">sort by date</a>
<div id="online">
  <!-- SQL_online.php ROW LOAD HERE -->
</div>
```

JQUERY/AJAX

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
     load_data();

     function load_data(query)
     {
      $.ajax({
       url:"SQL_online.php",
       method:"POST",
       data:{query:query},
       success:function(data)
       {
       $('#online').html(data);
       }
      });
     setTimeout(function(){load_data()}, 10000); /// refresh each 10s
     }

     $('.toto').click(function(){
      var search = $(this).attr('id');
      console.log (search);
      if(search != '')
      {
       load_data(search);
      }
      else
      {
       load_data();
      }
     });

    });
```

When ajax reload SQL i lost "sort by" selection. how to keep the "a" select id clicked ?Thanks !

Comment: cant u just send a query to your function ?
setTimeout(function(){load_data(query)}, 10000);

Comment: nice but there a problem. on load 'query' is undefined. With your solution result is good but don't stay, query have value undefined and after take id of a click, if i click again on other id query take all values in a while and result skip/jump :) Thank

Comment: i think on each clicked id that create a session reload, and each one reload after 10 secondes :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you to refresh your data every 10 sec and your query still works. im not sure it is what you exactly want!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 window._intervalId = setInterval(load_data(), 10000);

 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"SQL_online.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {
   $('#online').html(data);
   }
  });

 }

 $('.toto').click(function(){
  if (window._intervalId !== undefined){
  clearInterval(window._intervalId);
  }
  var search = $(this).attr('id');
  window._intervalId = setInterval(load_data(search), 10000); /// refresh each 10s
 });

});
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for or not... so i can edit my answer.

Comment: Thank :) but there's no refresh with your solution. On page loaded the div id "online" is not refresh after 10s and if i click on <a id, data is correctly load but div id "online" is not refresh after 10s too

Comment: are you sure you user `setInterval` ? you used `setTimeout` above !

Comment: note that refreshing data will start after you click one of `.toto` tags.
if you want auto refresh. let me know to change my answer

Comment: i'm sorry, i copy and paste your code and modify your mistake "undefiend => undefined" but i've no refresh and no activity network on console network (only have activity when i click toto class but no data refresh each 10s). if i change Something in database, data in div is refresh only if i click class tags filters, if Something change again the modification must be show on ajax refresh with the current class tags but not on clicking again on a other tags. Thank for your help

Comment: i updated my answer... it will refresh every 10 sec now.

Comment: i've no refresh... i clear cache etc, Nothing... Perhaps a compatibility problem ? Do you use a special lib ? have 2.1.3 jquery.min.js